# In Android: how to force a TextView to wrapt the content AND padding

Tags: android, height, padding

How would I make the `TextView_height=content_height+padding`
When I am adding some top-padding to the textbox - it moves the content behind the borders of the TextView.
This is right, since I made the TextView to be as tall as the content.

Is it possible to make the TextView as tall as content + padding?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="false"
tools:context=".DisplayActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TopmessageStripe"
    style="@style/TopmessageStripeTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:height="@dimen/big_margin"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you paste the xml definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely your problem

```
android:height="@dimen/big_margin"
```

It is setting a custom height instead of wrapping the content.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it using the gui but this might be what you're looking for in the xml for the text view

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mTextView"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
        >
    </TextView>
```

Comment: this is what I did. Have the problem with text exceeding the textView

Comment: I see that now, I had posted this before you added the xml. Yarakyo is correct though, you are setting the height twice and the second one is overwriting the first one.